# Showing continuity of a max function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

> Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $X$ where $(X,d)$ is a metric space.
>
> Define $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$. Show that $h$ is continuous on $X$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$

Without loss of generality, suppose $f(x_{0})>g(x_{0})$

$\implies |h(x)-h(x_{0})|=|h(x)-f(x_{0})|$

Since $g$ is continuous on $X$,

$\exists\space\delta_{0}>0$ such that if $|x-x_{0}|<\delta_{0}$ then $|g(x)-g(x_{0})|<f(x_{0})-g(x_{0})$ which implies $g(x)<f(x_{0})$

Since $f$ is continuous on $X$,

$\exists\space\delta_{1}\space(0<\delta_{1}\le\delta_{0})$ such that if $|x-x_{0}|<\delta_{1}$ then $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<f(x_{0})-g(x)$ which implies $f(x)>g(x)$

So let $\delta=\delta_{1}$

If $|x-x_{0}|<\delta$ then $|h(x)-f(x_{0})|=|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\epsilon$ since $f$ is continuous on $X$

$\therefore\space h$ is continous on $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that $h(x)=\frac{f(x)+g(x)+|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

No. That $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<f(x_{0})-g(x)$ which $f(x_{0})-g(x)$ has the variable $x$.

One can prove this assertion by observing that 
\begin{align*}
|h(x)-h(y)|&=|(f\vee g)(x)-(f\vee g)(y)|\\
&=|f(x)\vee g(x)-f(x)\vee g(y)+f(x)\vee g(y)-f(y)\vee g(y)|\\
&\leq|f(x)\vee g(x)-f(x)\vee g(y)|+|f(x)\vee g(y)-f(y)\vee g(y)|\\
&\leq|g(x)-g(y)|+|f(x)-f(y)|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would it still be wrong to say $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\epsilon<f(x_{0})-g(x)$?

Comment: That is not true. It is not guarantee that $\epsilon<f(x_{0})-g(x)$.

Comment: Since it is positive, we can find $\epsilon$ smaller than it but still positive no?

Comment: Then $\epsilon>0$ is not arbitrary, it is controlled by the variable $x$.

Comment: I mean, since $f$ is continuous, we can choose any $\epsilon$ we want. So we can take one smaller than the expression, for all $x$. Am I confused? The epsilon I choose here is different from the one I initially fixed, of course.

Comment: That $\epsilon>0$ is independent of $x$. It is that for all $|x-x_{0}|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\epsilon$, the $\epsilon>0$ appears first.

Comment: The epsilon I'm choosing is not the same one I fixed, it is one I choose by virtue of $f$ being continuous.

Comment: Then $\epsilon=\epsilon_{x}$ depends on $x$, and then when you choose the corresponding $\delta$, this also depends on $x$, that is, $\delta=\delta_{x}$, this cannot be going through. $\delta$ can depend on $x_{0}$, not $x$.

Comment: I see where I'm confused then! Thanks.

Comment: Is your $y$ fixed in the inequalities you are showing? How do you go from before last line to last line?

Comment: Yes, $y$ is fixed. The inequality that $|u\vee v-w\vee v|\leq|u-w|$ is from a more general theory called Riesz space, but in this case, you can just test it brutally, just let $u\geq v\geq w$, and then $u\geq v$, $w\geq v$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are not completely correct in your formulation of the proof. First $X$ is some abstract metric space, not necessarily $\mathbb{R}$. Second you need to use the metric function $d_X(\cdot,\cdot):X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $d_Y(\cdot,\cdot):Y\times Y\to \mathbb{R}^+$ in your arguments ($f,g:X\to Y$). For example the fact that $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be continuous in $X$ means that for any $x_0\in X$ you pick, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there are $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that 
$$d_X(x,x_0)<\delta_1\Rightarrow d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon\\
d_X(x,x_0)<\delta_1\Rightarrow d_Y(g(x),g(x_0))<\varepsilon$$
Now what you need to show is that $h(x):=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is continuous under the above assumptions. That means for every $x_0\in X$ and for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that 
$$d_X(x,x_0)<\delta\Rightarrow d_Y(h(x),h(x_0))<\varepsilon$$
Now suppose at $x_0$ we have $f(x_0)> g(x_0)$ (the other case is analogue). Then by triangle inequality
$$d_Y(h(x),h(x_0))=d_Y(h(x),f(x_0))\leqslant d_Y(h(x),f(x))+d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))$$
Since $f(x), g(x)$ are continuous and by assumption $f(x_0)>g(x_0)$ then there exists an open ball $B_{\delta}(x_0)$ where $ f(x)\geqslant g(x)$. Pick $\delta\leqslant \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ then 
$$d_Y(h(x),f(x))+d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))=d_Y(f(x),f(x))+d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))=d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$$ 
whenever $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$ i.e. whenever $x\in B_{\delta}(x_0)$. Hence $h(x)$ is a continuous function in $X$.